# Why do these processes stay blocked even though the semaphore supposedly frees them?

Tags: c, semaphore

I'm learning about synchronization with semaphores and message queues and I'm having a problem with an assignment.

I am trying to synchronize several child processes (the parent has a completely different function that is irrelevant to this question) so that when all of them get to a point they stop until everyone is ready, but when it's time to continue only one of them does.

I've made a small program simulating the code i have problems with.

Supposedly the "main" child process should receive one message per other child process and then free them so they can finish the program, however in practice only the "main" one continues.

The code i pasted does actually give me a segmentation fault, but i'm not sure if the reason is the same i had in the other project or something i overlooked whilst trying to make it similar to the original.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>



int sem, msgqueue, alive;

void childFunction(int i);

struct sembuf sopsEntrar1, sopsSalir1, sopsEntrar2, sopsSalir2;


union semun{
    int val;
    struct semid_ds *buf;   
    unsigned short *array;
}semn1, semn2;

//Message type

    
struct TipoDispara{
    long tipo;
    char dispara[2];    
};

struct TipoDispara td, tenv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    /*In the actual code there are checks to make sure the argvs are valid, 
    for the sake of this question any number higher than two will do*/
    alive= atoi(argv[1]);
    
    sopsEntrar1.sem_num=0;
    sopsEntrar1.sem_op=-1;
    sopsEntrar1.sem_flg=0;


    sopsSalir1.sem_num=0;
    sopsSalir1.sem_op=1;
    sopsSalir1.sem_flg=0;

    sopsEntrar2.sem_num=1;
    sopsEntrar2.sem_op=-1;
    sopsEntrar2.sem_flg=0;

    sopsSalir2.sem_num=1;
    sopsSalir2.sem_op=1;
    sopsSalir2.sem_flg=0;

    if((sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 2, IPC_CREAT | 0600))==-1){
        perror("Error al crear semaforos\n\n"); 
        fflush(stdout);
        exit -1;
    }

    semn1.val=1;

    if(semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, semn1)==-1){
        perror("Error inicializando sem 1\n\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        return -1;

    }
    
    if(semctl(sem, 1, SETVAL, semn1)==-1){
        perror("Error inicializando sem 2\n\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        return -1;

    }

    if((msgqueue = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | 0600))==-1){
        perror("Error al crear buzon\n\n"); 
        fflush(stdout);
        exit -1;
    }
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<alive;i++){
        switch(fork()){
            case -1:
                perror("Error al hacer el fork.\n\n");
                fflush(stdout);

                return -1;
                break;

            case 0:
                childFunction(i);

                return 0;
                break;
            default:

/*In the actual program it does something, here i'll make it sleep a few seconds 
to give the child processes some time before ending*/
            if(i=(alive-1)){
                sleep(10);
                if(semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID)==-1){
                    
                    printf("Error liberando semáforo\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                   
                }else{
                    printf("\n\n\nSemaforo liberado.\n\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
                if(msgctl(msgqueue, IPC_RMID, NULL)==-1){
                    
                    printf("Error liberando buzon\n");
                    fflush(stdout);

                }else{
                    printf("\n\n\nBuzon liberado.\n\n");
                    fflush(stdout);
                }
                return 1;
               
          }
          break;
    }


    
    
}
}
void childFunction(int i){
    
    td.tipo=2;
    /*In the actual program the way of choosing who goes in the if and who in 
    the else, here the only relevant thing is that only one of the children 
    processes go in the int*/
    if(i == 1){
        
        /*What shoud happen is that this process waits for the rest to send a
        message, one msgrcv per process that's supposed to send a message*/
        int j;
        for(j=1;j<alive;j++){
            if(msgrcv(msgqueue,&td, sizeof(td)-sizeof(long),2,0)){
                perror("error recibiendo mensajes");
                fflush(stdout);
           
                exit -1;
            }
            
        }
     /*After going through every message, frees the other processes,
     meaning every process alive but itself*/
    semop(sem, &sopsSalir2, (alive-1));
    }else{
        strcpy(td.dispara, "SI");
        if(msgsnd(msgqueue,&td, sizeof(td)-sizeof(long),0)){
           perror("error enviando mensaje");
           fflush(stdout);
           
           exit (-1);
        }
        /*After sending the message indicating they've arrived they wait for
        the "main" process to receive every message and free them*/
        semop(sem, &sopsEntrar2, 1);
    }
    printf("\nI'm process %d\n\n", i);

}
```

Comment: In the second snippet you want to receive a message (in the if part) and otherwise you want to send a message. The function calls look identical, which intrigues me: msgrcv(...) - Can you confirm that this is correct so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  You've reduced the code, which is admirable, but it is not clear that it can be compiled; I'm fairly sure this cannot.

Comment: @Ely Hi, thank you for your answer and i'm sorry i wasn't clear enough. The code is supposed to be used by several processes at the same time one of them (the if part) will supposedly wait for the rest by receiving a message each time one of them gets to the point. I'll edit this in a few minutes to better reflect that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry about that, it is my first time posting and i wasn't sure of how to do it, thank you for showing me those links i'll read them and edit the code accordingly

Comment: If `exit -1;` compiles, increase the warning level of your compiler. This assignment to `i` also looks highly suspicious: `if(i=(alive-1))`

Comment: Fwiw, I corrected the two mistakes I mentioned above and started it with an argument of `3` (as suggested by the comment in `main`) and then it ran and printed `I'm process 0` `error recibiendo mensajes: Success` `Semaforo liberado.` `Buzon liberado.` `I'm process 2`. The whole thing took 10 seconds, which seems reasonable since you have a `sleep(10);` in there.

Comment: The string copy is not correct. The size of the char array is 2 but you are sending "SI", which is size 3. You have to include the end of string in the count. So the char array should be of size 3. Maybe that is the seg fault that you are seeing?

Comment: And can you verify what `msgrcv` and `msgsnd` return? In many cases you check for `-1` but in these you don't.